# Calculate x,y position of rotated offset position?

Tags: math, matrix, geometry

I'm looking for a non matrix solution (basic geometry) for how to calculate an absolute x,y position C(x,y) of a rotated offset position. I know the parent position A, the amount of x,y offset B, and the rotation T. In the image axis B is offset from A and rotated from A by T degrees. I need to know C x and y.

[image: B offset from A and rotated by T degrees]

Answer (score 0):

(I consider Bx, By as positive values, distances)

Let's find corner point at first:

```
Px = Ax + By * Sin(T)
Py = Ay - By * Cos(T)
```

Then find C point

```
Cx = Px + Bx * Cos(T)
Cy = Py + Bx * Sin(T)
```

And combine them:

```
Cx = Ax + By * Sin(T) + Bx * Cos(T)
Cy = Ay - By * Cos(T) + Bx * Sin(T);
```